# Autoincrement varchar column optionally

Tags: sql, linq, ef-core-2.0

I have a table with guid identifier and one field that is a 5 characters string that can be specified by user, but it is optional, and it should be unique per user. I'm looking for a way to have this field always there, even if user doesn't specify it. The easiest approach is to have it like "00001", "00002"... etc. in case that user doesn't specify it, it is stored like this. I'm using SQL and entity framework core. What is the best way to achieve this?

EDIT: maybe trigger that will check after insert if that field is not specified and then just take current row number and convert it to string? does this make sense?
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Setting a default value to `'00001'` can be done define the field with:
 `NOT NULL DEFAULT right('0000' || to_char(SomeSequence.nextval),5)` (pseudo-code to be adapted to the DBMS you are connected to).
Compared to the solution in your EDIT, this will at least guarantee that 2 inserts at the same time from 2 different users get assigned different values.

The real problem comes with the `unique` constraint on the column. This does not work nicely when mixing manual input with calculated values.
If as a user, I input (manually) `00005`, then the insertion will fail when `SomeSequence` reaches 5.

I think this problem will exist regardless of how you implement the generation of values (sequence, trigger, external code, ...)
Even if you are fine with coding some additional (and probably complicated) logic to manage that, it will probably decrease concurrency.

Comment: i will probably move that field to a separate table and have autoincrement id, and string field, which will be created from id (id 1 -> field 00001) if its not provided. and i will have reference to that table from current one... what do you think about this approach?

Comment: I would need more details to say for sure. You can put the string field in the same table I think. just needs to be created with NULL (= null values are allowed) and UNIQUE (= if not null, the value is unique).